# Python error - can't assign to literal

Tags: python

```
FileName = 'Binarydata.dat'
BinaryFile = open(FileName, 'r')
for '0' in BinaryFile:
    print('')
else:
    print('@')
BinaryFile.close()
```

I am receiveing the error `SyntaxError - can't assign to literal` when trying to run this code. This is just a small part of the code. The rest is working correctly. I can't figure out why this is not working.

Comment: What exactly are you going for here? Using `'0'` as a for-each variable doesn't particularly make sense...?

Comment: what your looking for is for x in BinaryData: if x is 0: print('')

Comment: `I can't figure out why this is not working.` Then maybe you can try http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Answer (score 14):

```
for '0' in BinaryFile:
```

Where you have '0' should be a variable, not a literal.

Probably what you mean to do is:

```
for line in BinaryFile:
  if line == '0':
    print('')
  else:
    print('@')
```

Comment: Also note: `for x in BinaryFile:` - each `x` will be a line from the file, not a byte.

Comment: unless you open the file with rb instead of just r

Comment: I made a mistake in the question... it won't be if "line == 0", what would it be for a single character? Is there a built in function or will I have already assigned a variable?

Comment: Whilst this doesn't give an error, the program still doesn't work as it should. The binary file which is 1010110 should change to @ @ @@ , however it is still 1010110

Comment: you might need to loop through each character in line. Maybe `for char in line:` before the if statement. You can debug it by putting `print line` after the first `for`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably in the entire stacktrace you saw something like:

```
    for '0' in BinaryFile:
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

When python loops over BinaryFile, it assigns each iteration to a variable. In this case, you trying to assign the first iteration to '0', which is a string.

It should look like this instead:

```
    for a_variable in BinaryFile:
```

In this case, the element of BinaryFile will be assigned to a_variable. On the next iteration, the next variable will be assigned to a_variable.

This will continue until the object BinaryFile raises StopIteration error, at which point the iteration ends.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for `'0'`, then you can write:

```
for ch in BinaryFile:
    print('' if ch == '0' else '@')
```

Remember:  The `for` in Python is a for-each loop.  There has to be a variable bound over the contents of the iterable.