# what does can't assign to literal mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been writing programs in python, but then it comes up with can't assign to literal, What does it mean? and What causes it? I've searched to try and find this but I can't find it.

Comment: I think that it means that you can't assign to a literal. Something like "name" = "Bob" is bad (since "name" is a literal string) but name = "Bob" is okay (since name is a valid variable)

Answer (score 7):

The object on the left-hand side of an assignment statement can not be a literal. [A literal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is a string, number, tuple, list, dict, boolean, or `None`. For example, all these raise `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`:

```
>>> 'foo' = 1
>>> 5 = 1
>>> [1, 2] = 3
```

This SyntaxError can also [happen through an indirect assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10090769/190597):

```
>>> for 'foo' in [1,2,3]:
....    pass
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

In the for-loop, Python tries to assign the values 1, 2, 3 to the literal string `'foo'`, which raises the SyntaxError.

The fix, of course, is to supply a variable name such as `foo`, not the string, `'foo'`:

```
for foo in [1,2,3]:
    pass
```